# Separate GIS points into groups of points that are close to each other

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

Have set of coordinates that need to be separated into groups that are close to each other.

Working with Python against a PostgreSQL database. I figured out a solution that would work, but then I realized that I'm probably re-inventing the wheel. Are there libraries that I can use to accomplish this without having roll my own solution?

**Example:**

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two good solutions implemented directly in PostGIS in the answers to this GIS SE question:

[**Spatial clustering with PostGIS**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/spatial-clustering-with-postgis)

You can also find some useful pointers in the answers to:

[**How to identify clusters in vector point data?**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11342/how-to-identify-clusters-in-vector-point-data)